# How do I avoid modal from closing if errors in validation(php)?

Tags: javascript, validation, modal-dialog

```js
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
 abrirPopup= document.getElementById('abrir-popup'),
 abrirPopupFooter= document.getElementById('abrir-popup-footer'),
 overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
 popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
 btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');
 

btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
 overlay.classList.add('active');
 popup.classList.add('active');
});

abrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
 overlay.classList.add('active');
 popup.classList.add('active');
});

abrirPopupFooter.addEventListener('click', function(){
 overlay.classList.add('active');
 popup.classList.add('active');
});

btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 overlay.classList.remove('active');
 popup.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```html
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <div class="popup" id="popup">
  <?php
    if(isset($errores)):?>
      <ul class="alert alert-danger">
        <?php
        foreach ($errores as $key => $value) :?>
          <li> <?=$value;?> </li>
          <?php endforeach;?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif;?>

    <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
    <h3>Registrate!</h3>
    <h4>Y forma parte de nuestra comunidad!</h4>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data" >
      <div class="contenedor-inputs">
        <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre"  value="<?=(isset($errores["nombre"]) )? "" : inputUsuario("nombre");?>" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input name="apellido" type="text" id="apellido"  value="<?=(isset($errores["apellido"]) )? "" : inputUsuario("apellido");?>" placeholder="Apellido">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?=isset($errores["email"])? "":inputUsuario("email") ;?>" placeholder="Correo">
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input name="repassword" type="password" id="repassword" value="" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña">
        <input  type="file" name="avatar" value=""/>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="registro" class="btn-submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

When click on Submit modal closes even though there are errors. Wan to avoid that.

When I reopen the modal errors do appear but would like the modal to stay open and only close if there are no errors during the validation.

I leave HTML and JS. 
THANKS!

Comment: Please add html code to your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Also where is the code where you treat the errors in order to avoid submit ? the js code above only changes css classes.

Comment: You're mixing client and server concepts. First you don't have any js in order to validate the code in the client and that avoids submitting values to server. Then you have a server variable $errores which isn't being created anywhere. So first you have to decide: you want to validate on the client with javascript and send to server, you want to validate on the server with php and render a page with errors or you want to do both ?

Comment: If you want client only validation you delete the PHP $error part and write js code to validate. If you want server only you write php code before the `if(isset($errores))` part and populate $errores based on the data sent by the client's form. If you want both you create both js and php parts and delete  nothing.